# Right way to terminate a trio program without BrokenResourceError

Tags: python-trio

My app follows a Producer and Consumer pattern. There's a Producer, 2 task (A, B), and a Consumer.

Producer reads an sql table and outputs to A & B. They in turn performs some task on that output and sends to Consumer. Consumer reads from A & B and then outputs to an s3 file.

There is a memory channel between Producer & A, Producer & B, A & Consumer, B & Consumer.

This is how I terminate my program right now (once producers have exhausted all the rows in the SQL table):

```
async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
    nursery.start_soon(A.run)
    nursery.start_soon(B.run)
    nursery.start_soon(consumer.run)
    
    while True:
        rowcount = await producer_task.run()
        if not rowcount:
            logging.info('Producer exiting loop')

            # Terminate the tasks' inner loops
            for t in (A, B, consumer):
                t.is_terminated = True

            # Let subtasks wrap up
            await trio.sleep(60 * 5)

            # Terminate all send_channels, subtasks can be stuck receiving.
            for channel in all_channels.keys():
                await channel.aclose()

            break
```

This is the base class of A & B:

```
class AsyncSubtask(object):
    def __init__(self, receive_channel, send_channel):
        self.receive_channel = receive_channel
        self.send_channel = send_channel
        self.is_terminated = False

    async def run(self):
        try:
            while not self.is_terminated:
                input_work = await self.receive_channel.receive()
                if input_work:
                    output_work = await self.loop(input_work)
                    await self.send_channel.send(output_work)
                    logging.info(f'{self.__class__.__name__} -> {self.get_logging_name(output_work)}')
                else:
                    logging.warning(f'{self.__class__.__name__} received empty inputs.')
        except trio.EndOfChannel:
            pass

        logging.info(f'{self.__class__.__name__} exiting loop')

    async def loop(self, work):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def get_logging_name(self, output_work):
        return len(output_work)
```

Right now, my program is not exiting successfully due to this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/myfile/bin/fetch_ott_features.py", line 386, in <module>
    trio.run(parent)
  File "/myfile/lib/python3.6/site-packages/trio/_core/_run.py", line 1896, in run
    raise runner.main_task_outcome.error
  File "/myfile/bin/fetch_ott_features.py", line 379, in parent
    break
  File "/myfile/lib/python3.6/site-packages/trio/_core/_run.py", line 741, in __aexit__
    raise combined_error_from_nursery
  File "/myfile/lib/python3.6/site-packages/a9_ifs_user_reach/async_util.py", line 27, in run
    await self.send_channel.send(output_work)
  File "/myfile/lib/python3.6/site-packages/trio/_channel.py", line 178, in send
    await trio.lowlevel.wait_task_rescheduled(abort_fn)
  File "/myfile/lib/python3.6/site-packages/trio/_core/_traps.py", line 166, in wait_task_rescheduled
    return (await _async_yield(WaitTaskRescheduled(abort_func))).unwrap()
  File "/myfile/lib/python3.6/site-packages/outcome/_sync.py", line 111, in unwrap
    raise captured_error
trio.BrokenResourceError
```

Note: the `break` in line 379 is referencing to the last line in the `async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery` block above.

It seems the way I am terminating my program is causing this issue. I have ran this on two separate occasions and gotten the same error.

How should I terminate my program without causing this error?

Answer (score 4):

The traceback says that the `BrokenResourceError` is coming from a call to `await send_channel.send(...)`.

`send_channel.send` raises this error if you're trying to send some data and the receiving end of the channel was already closed.

I suspect the issue is that when do

```py
for channel in all_channels.keys():
    await channel.aclose()
```

...you're actually closing *all* of the channels, including one that's still in use.

If you have data flowing from Producer -> A/B -> Consumer, then the usual pattern for handling shutdown would be:

1. Producer finishes reading the table and determines that it has nothing more to send.
2. Producer closes *its* channel objects and exits.
3. A/B eventually finish processing everything in the channel, and then get notified that the Producer has closed it. If you're using `async for blah in receive_channel: ...`, then the loop will terminate once everything is done. If you're calling `receive_channel.receive()`, then you'll get an `EndOfChannel` exception that you can catch.
4. A/B close *their* channel objects and exit.
5. Consumer eventually finishes processing everything in their incoming channel, and then get notified that A/B have closed it. Consumer exits.

tl;dr: If you write each of your tasks like:

```py
async def producer(send_to_ab):
    async with send_to_ab:
        async for row in fetch_rows_somewhere():
            await send_to_ab.send(ab)

async def a_or_b(receive_from_producer, send_to_consumer):
    async with receive_from_producer, send_to_consumer:
        async for row in receive_from_producer:
            result = await do_stuff_with(row)
            await send_to_consumer.send(result)

async def consumer(receive_from_ab):
    async with receive_from_ab:
        async for result in receive_from_ab:
            await put_in_s3(result)
```

...then it should all clean itself up and terminate automatically and reliably.